# Get user screen size in javascript and resize the image into a temporary file and load it up in the background

Tags: javascript, php

```
.roof {
    background-image: url('roof.png');
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 10% 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:500;
}
```

Here the php code.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46431913/image.php

The problem with the code is that it cant get the screen size or div size where I want my images to fit in. The dimensions are fixed. Would be great if you could give me some insight.

Comment: The viewport dimensions are unavailable server-side (which is where PHP executes). Therefore, you need javascript to bridge this by using an XHR to bridge the gap between the client and the server. You will need a custom function to handle the receiving of this XHR call on the server-side that can pass along dimensions to the PHP script as arguments to be executed.

Comment: could be very server intensive doing this for every visitor

Comment: Have you tried using background-size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using background-size or max-width (inline) for your images? What you are trying to will put too much strain on your server.